# ag-Grid javaScript, TypeError: rowData is undefined

Tags: ag-grid

ag-Grid, following the [official demo](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-tree/#gsc.tab=0) of javascript but using API like real world over hard-coded data. Note: no jQuery, just use the primitive plain XMLHttpRequest() for ajax.

- F12 verified API returns data in the same structure as demo, has *children* node inside, and gripOptions.rowData is assigned with the returned data.
- Tried instantiating `rowData` inside of `gripOptions` as 
  `rowData: [],`  got the same error
  Or
  `rowData: {},`  got ReferenceError: rowData is not defined.

HTML:

```
<script src="/scripts/agGrid/ag-grid.js"></script>
<script src="/scripts/agGrid/myAG.js"></script>
<br />JavaScript ag-Grid
<div id="myGrid" style="height: 200px;" class="ag-fresh"></div>
```

myAG.js:

```
var httpApi = new XMLHttpRequest();
var columnDefs = [
    { headerName: "Client Name", field: "ClientName", unSortIcon: true, cellRenderer: "group" },
    { headerName: "Division", field: "Division" },
    { headerName: "Others", field: "Others" }
];
var gridOptions = {
    columnDefs: columnDefs,
    getNodeChildDetails: getNodeChildDetails
};

function getNodeChildDetails(rowItem) {
    if (rowItem.ClientName) {
        return {
            group: true,

        // provide ag-Grid with the children of this group
            children: rowItem.children,

            // the key is used by the default group cellRenderer
            key: rowItem.ClientName
        };
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

// wait for the document to be loaded, otherwise
// ag-Grid will not find the div in the document.
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/api/myAG/Tree",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            gridOptions.rowData = data;
            var eGridDiv = document.querySelector('#myGrid');
            new agGrid.Grid(eGridDiv, gridOptions);
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(errorThrown);
        }
    })

});
```

Version: 
ag-grid = v8.1.0
FireFox = 50.1.0

Error message:
[image: Error msg]

F12 confirms data exists and assigned:

[image: F12 confirmed data exists and assigned]

inside of ag-grid.js, the line it complains about but rowData has data: 
[image: rowData has data inside of ag-grid.js where the error complains about]

Comment: If I take out the Tree Data grouping stuff, it displays the parent level data in the grid.

Comment: is it because some children has no content inside?

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42605168/ag-grid-try-to-make-tree-demo-work-using-own-data

Answer (score 0):

See this answered post, basically an additional check is needed for the tree.

[ag-Grid, try to make Tree Demo work using own data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42605168/ag-grid-try-to-make-tree-demo-work-using-own-data)