# ag-Grid, try to make Tree Demo work using own data

Tags: ag-grid

I like the ag-Grid because it's less buggy, fast and works with many frameworks.

So I tried the Tree Data, no need to tell the link between parents and children, simply lay down the data in structure, specify some options, Bingo! But, when I plug in my API, it tells me

> "TypeError: rowData is undefined"

from inside of ag-grid.js even though Watch clearly shows it has the array. There are some answered Question here regarding customization with internal api. Mine is not.

I then use the official demo as a base, set up a Fiddler to grab the raw data in JSON replace demo data to make it hardcoded for a test to determine if it's problem with own API or something else. Here is the [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/PS4jAzTiNnulV3iBHPOb?p=preview). Note it's totally based on the official javaScript Demo of [Tree Data](https://ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-tree/#gsc.tab=0), **Tree Data Example**, the first one.

In case you don't want to see Plunker, here is my .js:

```
var columnDefs = [
    {headerName: "Client", field: "Client", cellRenderer: 'group'},
    {headerName: "Program", field: "Program"}
    /*{headerName: "Group", field: "xgroup", cellRenderer: 'group'}, // cellRenderer: 'group'}, -- this "group" is one of the default value option for built-in cellRenderer function, not field.
    //{headerName: "Athlete", field: "athlete"},
    //{headerName: "Year", field: "year"},
    {headerName: "Country", field: "country"}
    */
];

var myData = [
    {
      'Client': 'Goodle',
      'Program': 'no grid',
      'kids': []
    },
    {
      'Client': 'Facebrook',
      'Program': 'grids',
      'kids': [
        {
          'Client': 'Facebrook',
          'Program': 'ag-Grid'
        },
        {
          'Client': 'Facebrook',
          'Program': 'ui-grid'
        }
      ]
    }
    /*{xgroup: 'Group A',
        participants: [
        /*{athlete: 'Michael Phelps', year: '2008', country: 'United States'},
        {athlete: 'Michael Phelps', year: '2008', country: 'United States'},
        {athlete: 'Michael Phelps', year: '2008', country: 'United States'}*/
    /*]},
    {xgroup: 'Group B', athlete: 'Sausage', year: 'Spaceman', country: 'Winklepicker',
        participants: [
        {athlete: 'Natalie Coughlin', year: '2008', country: 'United States'},
        {athlete: 'Missy Franklin ', year: '2012', country: 'United States'},
        {athlete: 'Ole Einar Qjorndalen', year: '2002', country: 'Norway'},
        {athlete: 'Marit Bjorgen', year: '2010', country: 'Norway'},
        {athlete: 'Ian Thorpe', year: '2000', country: 'Australia'}
    ]},
    {xgroup: 'Group C',
        participants: [
        {athlete: 'Janica Kostelic', year: '2002', country: 'Crotia'},
        {athlete: 'An Hyeon-Su', year: '2006', country: 'South Korea'}
    ]}*/
];

var gridOptions = {
    columnDefs: columnDefs,
    rowData: myData,
    rowSelection: "single",
    enableSorting: "true", unSortIcon: "true",
    enableColResize: "true",
    enableRangeSelection: "true",
    suppressCellSelection: "false",
    showToolPanel: "true",
    supressCopyRowsToClipboard: true,
    supressCellSelection: false,
    getNodeChildDetails: getNodeChildDetails,
    onGridReady: function(params) {
        params.api.sizeColumnsToFit();
    }
};

function getNodeChildDetails(rowItem) {
    if (rowItem.Client) {
        return {
            group: true,

            // open C be default
            //expanded: rowItem.ClientName === 'Group C',

            // provide ag-Grid with the children of this group
            children: rowItem.kids,

            // this is not used, however it is available to the cellRenderers,
            // if you provide a custom cellRenderer, you might use it. it's more
            // relavent if you are doing multi levels of groupings, not just one
            // as in this example.
            //field: 'group',

            // the key is used by the default group cellRenderer
            key: rowItem.Client
        };
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

function onFilterChanged(value) {
    gridOptions.api.setQuickFilter(value);
}


// setup the grid after the page has finished loading
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var gridDiv = document.querySelector('#myGrid');
    new agGrid.Grid(gridDiv, gridOptions);
});
```

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <!-- you don't need ignore=notused in your code, this is just here to trick the cache -->
    <script src="https://ag-grid.com/dist/ag-grid/ag-grid.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <input placeholder="Filter..." type="text"
           onpaste="onFilterChanged(this.value)"
           oninput="onFilterChanged(this.value)"
           onchange="onFilterChanged(this.value)"
           onkeydown="onFilterChanged(this.value)"
           onkeyup="onFilterChanged(this.value)"/>
    <div id="myGrid" class="ag-fresh" style="height: 450px; margin-top: 4px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Need some experts!

Answer (score 1):

You need to alter getNodeChildDetails to have this:

```
function getNodeChildDetails(rowItem) {
    if (rowItem.Client && rowItem.kids && rowItem.kids.length > 0) {
```

As you have it you're telling the grid that any item with `Client` is a parent node, but what you really mean in your data is any item with Client AND kids is a parent.

Remember that the grid can have multiple levels so a child can be a parent too.

Comment: wow, it works! But why the demo doesn't need that given the fact mine just mimic the demo?

Comment: In the demo the child data is different - the child rows do not have a "group" field so the getNodeChildDetails doesnt consider them to be potential parent rows

Comment: Child rows don't have any field contains "group". Only parents have a data field named **"group"**. Rename to **"xgroup"**, still works. Take a look at this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/btiAzlRSWOnTjuNdvWfD?p=preview). Does ag-Grid look for a data field whose name contains _group_ and treat it as a parent?

Comment: There's nothing special about group in this case - its just a label. In the plunker you've change both the property and the check in getNodeChildDetails to both be rowItem.xgroup, so it still works.

Comment: **1)** _"group"_ is a literal option for `cellRenderer` of `columnDefs`, it's not the data field of parent or child, right? **2)** field name of data source has changed to _**x**group_ from _group_, hence `function getNodeChildDetails()` is changed to `if (rowItem.xgroup)` from `if (rowItem.group)` accordingly. My understanding is both _xgroup_ and _group_ are data field names, right?  If correct then **3)** why simply `if (rowItem.xgroup)` works no need to do `if (rowItem.xgroup && rowItem.participants && rowItem.participants.length > 0)` as you suggested on my dataset? Thanks.